# $area returning NULL for some areas

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

Dataset: English Regions boundaries, merged with those of Wales and Scotland, all from the ONS (UK stats body). Creates a multi-polygon layer because of the islands within each region.

Problem: Adding a column in the attribute table for $area, returns NULL for all areas except London (the smallest).

To try and narrow down the issue I converted the multi-polygon to singles, then ran $area again and it produced values for the smaller areas (islands), but not for the main areas (eg Scottish Mainland, West Midlands etc), it also didn't produce a value for the large Isle of Lewis, but it was still OK for London (which I think is smaller than Lewis), so I think this is possibly to do with the size of the areas, but why? And how do I work around it?

I have also converted the polygons to lines and back to polygons jut in case it highlighted a problem with the polygons, but still had the same result.

Any ideas?

In the image below: red highlighted areas are producing NULL for $area, green areas returning values for $area.

[image: red highlighted areas produce NULL for $area, the green areas are returning values OK]

Comment: Have you tried [fixing the geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisfixgeometries)?

Comment: Hi, I hadn't, as I didn't know there was such a function, so thanks for that. But in this case it didn't work.

Comment: can you add a link to the file you are using? I would usually use the OS BoundaryLine data for this sort of thing - which comes with an Area in Hectares already

Comment: Here: http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/4fcca2a47fed4bfaa1793015a18537ac_0    There is an area field, but I want to calculate it myself, and also it seems to affect the ability to do calculations once I do Intersections etc with other layers.

Comment: I've just used the OS BoundaryLine data (European regions) and it's done exactly the same as the ONS data - and not calculated the larger areas. (Useful dataset though!)

Comment: I just downloaded the file in the link (English Regions) and added a new area field without issue (Type: Decimal (real), Length: 10, Precision, 2). Maybe it could be something to do with the merge you're doing with the other dataset. Try adding area to them pre-merge and see if this highlights something?